# Jetpack Compose Navigation - pass argument to startDestination

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

The app I'm building uses compose navigation with routes. The challenge is that the start destination is dynamic.

Here is a minimal example:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = "dynamic/1", // doesn't work
                // startDestination = "static", // workaround
            ) {
                composable(
                    route = "dynamic/{$ARG_ID}",
                    arguments = listOf(navArgument(ARG_ID) { type = NavType.StringType }),
                ) {
                    val id = it.arguments?.getString(ARG_ID)
                    Text("dynamic route, received argument: $id!")
                }
                // part of the workaround
                // composable(
                //  route = "static",
                // ) {
                //  LaunchedEffect(this) {
                //      navController.navigate("dynamic/1")
                //  }
                // }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object
    {
        const val ARG_ID = "id"
    }
}
```

The app crashes with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination route/1 is not a direct child of this NavGraph
```

The problem only exists if the "dynamic" route is used as start destination. This can be verified by using `startDestination = "static"`.

Although, the "static" route workaround works I'm looking for a solution without it because it kind of obfuscates the code and also creates an additional entry in the back stack.

-> [Full code sample](https://github.com/p-fischer/compose-navigation-startdestination-with-argument) to reproduce the issue

Related SO questions

- [Navigation Architecture Component- Passing argument data to the startDestination](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50334550/2011622) - Answers don't seem to be applicable to Compose Navigation.
- [Pass an argument to a nested navigation graph in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70086094/2011622) - No answer given.
- [Compose Navigation - navigation destination ... is not a direct child of this NavGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69038660/2011622) - The accepted answer doesn't resolve the issue.

**Edit:**

I want to stress that the original sample used to not contain the "static" composable. I only added the "static" composable to have a working `startDestination` and to prove that the "dynamic" composable can be navigated to.

**Update:**

Even switching to the [query parameter syntax for optional arguments](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#optional-args), providing a default value, and setting the start destination without any argument does not work.

The following variation

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "dynamic",
) {
    composable(
        route = "dynamic?$ARG_ID={$ARG_ID}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument(ARG_ID) { type = NavType.StringType; defaultValue = "1" }),
    ) {
        val id = it.arguments?.getString(ARG_ID)
        Text("dynamic route, received argument: $id!")
    }
}
```

Leads to the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination dynamic is not a direct child of this NavGraph
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compose Navigation - navigation destination ... is not a direct child of this NavGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038660/compose-navigation-navigation-destination-is-not-a-direct-child-of-this-na) (answer from Compose maintainer)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov No, unfortunately it doesn't. Reading all comments the accepted answer seems to not fully resolve the original issue there... or did you catch something I can apply to my sample? 
I'm going to add the question to my related questions list.

Comment: Rather than have `static` call `navController.navigate("dynamic/1")`, just have it call your real content composable for the dynamic scenario, passing in `"1"` as a hard-coded value, rather than getting it from the arguments `Bundle`. That avoids the additional entry in the back stack, and it would not seem to be especially complex.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! Could you please elaborate where you'd call `navController.navigate("dynamic/1")` and what you would set as `startDestination`?

Comment: "Could you please elaborate where you'd call navController.navigate("dynamic/1")" -- I suggested *not* doing that. Keep the `static` route, but have it call the same function that your `dynamic` route does, just with a hard-coded `"1"` parameter, rather than getting the value from the arguments bundle.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, I finally got your point.
What I still don't get is why start destinations with arguments don't work. I see this as an unpredictable limitation or simply a bug.
The workaround with a "static" route requires to take this additional route into account in the back stack, e.g. when using `popUpTo()` and for the decision which bottom bar item needs to be marked selected given the current route.

Comment: OK, have you tried [using `defaultValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavArgument#defaultValue()) on your `dynamic` argument, to perhaps avoid setting a value when it is your start destination? That might require you to make it an [optional argument](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation?hl=en#nav-with-args).

Comment: @CommonsWare I extended the original post with a sample using optional arguments. This stills throws the same exception. "dynamic" only works as `startDestination` if I remove any arguments from the `composable` `route` but then the route can't be navigated to with arguments - all call-side arguments are ignored if only declared in the `arguments` list but not mentioned in the route.

Comment: The string `"dynamic"` you use for your `startDestination` needs to match, character by character, the exact string you use in your `composable` `route`: it needs to be `"dynamic?$ARG_ID={$ARG_ID}"`.

Comment: Thank you so much @ianhanniballake! I always assumed that `startDestination` needed to be a concrete route (containing the arguments' values). Wouldn't it be a cool feature if that was possible? Then, arguments wouldn't require a default value and could be declared as truly mandatory.

Comment: this is a crazy question :)

Answer (score 49):

Full credit goes to [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake), who explained the solution to me in a comment. I'm going to show the working version of my code sample here.

The big insight to me was:

**`startDestination` must not match a composable `route` in the sense of pattern matching but it must be exactly the same string**.

That means an argument can't be set via `startDestination` directly but has to be set via the argument's `defaultValue`.

Here is the working sample:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                // 1st change: Set startDestination to the exact string of route
                startDestination = "dynamic/{$ARG_ID}", // NOT "dynamic/1", provide arguments via defaultValue
            ) {
                composable(
                    route = "dynamic/{$ARG_ID}",
                    // 2nd change: Set startDestination argument via defaultValue
                    arguments = listOf(navArgument(ARG_ID) { type = NavType.StringType; defaultValue = "1" }),
                ) {
                    val id = it.arguments?.getString(ARG_ID)
                    Text("dynamic route, received argument: $id!")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object
    {
        const val ARG_ID = "id"
    }
}
```

The approach equally works with the argument provided in the form of a query parameter.

To be honest, I see this as a small limitation because the start route now dictates what has to be the `defaultValue`. I might want to set a different `defaultValue` or none at all. Yet, in most cases this should be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @ianhanniballake would be great to have that info in the official docs

Comment: Thanks for this answer, your assumption was also my intuitive sense; if Compose Navigation is supposed to operate similarly to URL navigation, I think it would work in that way. I agree with @MTomczynski, this edge case should be in the official documentation.

Comment: end of the day! we can't change the default value dynamically. for __startDestination__

Answer (score 1):

All credit goes to [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) and [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011622/peter-f). In my case I didn't add any additional (mandatory key/optional key) in route for the argument data. I kept the route clean like below:

Nav graph:

```
 navigation(route = Route.Root.route, startDestination = Route.SubmitForm.route) {

    composable(
        route = Route.SubmitForm.route,
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument(ARG_KEY) {
                type = NavType.StringType
                defaultValue = JsonConverter.toJson(user, User::class.java)
            },
        )
    )
}
```

Route sealed class:

```
sealed class Route(val route: String) {
    object MyRoute : Route("$ROOT/submit-form")
}
```

And in view model just get the data like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    stateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel {

    lateinit var user

    init {
        user = stateHandle.get<String>(ARG_NAME) // Supported data types
    }
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your first screen requires dynamic data fetched from an api or something like that, the default value won't do it.

It's not the cleanest solution. But you can compose an empty dummy screen first, after it loads you can navigate to the actual home screen

```
    var isPlaced by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LaunchedEffect(isPlaced) {
        if (isPlaced) {
            navController.navigate("home/some-argument") {
                launchSingleTop = true
            }
        }
    }


    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "start"
        ) {

            composable("start") {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                        isPlaced = true
                    }
                ) {}
            }

            composable(
                "home/{argument}",
            ) { backStackEntry ->
                backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(argument)?.let {
                HomeScreen(it)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

should not be using dynamic route value in "startDestination" NavHost
-->  navController.navigate(<dynamic route ‌>)

Answer (score -1):

What I did was explicitly navigate again in case start destination has params.

This way we also have to pop up the stack to remove initial navigation to start destination without params.

This solution might not work in all scenarios, but was enough to get me out of the situation.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    delay(500)
    if (doesStartDestinationHaveArgs(startDestination)) {
        navController.popBackStack()
        navController.navigate(startDestination)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this official documentation

[https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation][1]

```
    composable(
    "profile?userId={userId}",
    arguments = listOf(navArgument("userId") { defaultValue = "user1234" })
) { backStackEntry ->
    Profile(navController, backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("userId"))
}
```

But it has only one limitation you can't pass boolean in args for eg if you replace userId with any boolean value it does not work when you use it in start destination.