# navigation argument always taking default value or null in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying navigation in Android Jetpack Compose. But the problem is when I try to get the parameter using `navBackStackEntry` it always gives `null` or the default value which I have set.

I am using following gradle dependencies for navigation:

> implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.1"

Here is the complete code for the reference:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            TryingSomethingTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavHost(
                        navController = navController,
                        startDestination = "profile/12345"
                    ) {
                        composable(
                            route = "profile/{id}",
                            arguments = listOf(
                                navArgument("id") {
                                    type = NavType.StringType
                                    defaultValue = "invalid"
                                }
                            )
                        ) {
                            Log.d("MyTag", "id: ${it.arguments?.getString("id")}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @HanifShaikh Why I use any kind of `viewModel` can you explain how it depends on `viewModel` although I haven't use any :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are just experimenting. It is not recommended to use a dynamic value in the Start Destination. In fact, the dynamic value you use here, *12345*, should be the `defaultValue` you gave. If you try `navigate`, you can access the `ID`.

```
navController.navigate("profile/1234")
```

But if this is something you specifically want, you can find alternative solutions in previously answered questions here. You can try them, but I believe you are just experimenting.

[Jetpack Compose Navigation - pass argument to startDestination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404038/jetpack-compose-navigation-pass-argument-to-startdestination)